# Inside Azure DevOps Release pipeline, mvn release:prepare running into error with git symbolic-ref HEAD

Tags: git, maven, azure-devops

I have configured a Release pipeline in Azure DevOps to create a release and deploy my application. When running `mvn release:prepare --batch-mode`, I keep running into
`An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried updating the scm information in pom.xml from SSH to HTTPS and the otherwise as well. Every attempt leads to the same error.

Please let me know if you need any additional details.

[image: Release Pipeline Configuration w/ Shallow Depth 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref.

From the error message, the SCM Command is detecting the ref HEAD on current Branch.

The cause of the issue could be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo branch.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

In Release Pipeline, you can select the target Release Repo Artifacts and set the option:**Shallow fetch depth** to 0.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Kevin, I did set the shallow fetch depth to 0 in the release pipeline yet I'm running into the same error.

Comment: @sravan Can you share some details about the scm commnad in your pom.xml file ?

Comment: @sravan can you try to run the git command: **git checkout branchname** or **git checkout -f branchname** before you run the mvn release

Comment: I've added my release pipeline configuration screenshot for reference.

Comment: @sravan Can you share some details about the scm commnad in your pom.xml file ?  From the Pipeline overview interface, it has no issue.

Comment: From the pipeline configuration page, you are checking out the develop branch. In scm git command, are you also operating on the developer branch? If you are working on other branch, you may need to checkout the related git branch

Comment: I found the issue, once i moved the mvn release prepare to my CI pipeline and enabled `fetchDepth: 0`. The pipeline worked!